# how to change the terminal path to default?

Tags: python, terminal, pythonpath

I am actually a beginner and i tried setting up my python 3.6.5 path and i fondled with etc/paths/ and .zshrc file
and now when I open terminal, this is what I see

```
Last login: Sun Nov 14 19:13:31 on ttys000

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct  2 2021, 04:20:39) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.1) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploymen on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [unix.se] instead. FWIW, it sounds like you added a command like `exec python2` or just `python2` to your zshrc, but I don't use Zsh or Mac OS so my expertise ends there. BTW, welcome to SO!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.